# Setting up a Git repository on MacOS X with network drive

Tags: macos, git, network-drive

**The given:**

A mac with my work folder set up as Git repository.
A network drive (Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex Home, if that helps).

**The task:**

Set up the specific folder on my network drive as a place where a backup of my repository can be stored.

**What I tried:**

Setting up the location through Volumes path as a Remote (via Add Remote in Git GUI) - returned with:

```
fatal: GIT_WORK_TREE (or --work-tree=<directory>) is not allowed without specifying GIT_DIR (or --git-dir=<directory>
```

Then, I tried

```
git --git-dir=Volumes/xxxxxxx/GoFlex_Home/Personal/xxxxxxxx
```

in the terminal, and though it did not turn up with an error, it does not appear to be of result, as another try to add remote ended with the same error as above.

After that, I started to have doubts if specifying the path to network drive through Volumes and/or trying to add it as remote are the right things to do to solve the task. Maybe there are other ways to accomplish the goal that I am not yet aware of?

Comment: Have you cloned the repository in the network drive?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you get these errors because nothing exist yet in the network share. A remote must point to an existing repository, so you first have to clone it: in the original repo do:

```
git clone --bare . /Volumes/xxxxxxx/GoFlex_Home/Personal/xxxxxxxx
```

This will copy your repository data to the network folder.

Then you can add it as a remote:

```
git remote add --mirror=push backup /Volumes/xxxxxxx/GoFlex_Home/Personal/xxxxxxxx
```

You will be able to synchronize both with:

```
git push backup
```